# I want to delete the currently executing folder and its content in poweshell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

```
        $Path = Get-Location | Select -expand Path
        Set-Location ..
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath "FolderLocation" -Recurse -Force
```

This isn't working when I execute the powershell file through .cmd file.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$Path = Get-Location
Set-Location ..
Remove-Item -Path $Path -Recurse -Force
```

This worked for me but I did not have any files or folders in that folder.

Comment: I have tried this before. but the $Path here in Remove-Item is pointing to C:\ drive since my content is under C:\Temp\ and it is not deleting the folder also.